# Can box jellyfish see with their eyes?

Tags: marine-biology

While normal jellyfish don't have any eyes, box jellyfish have 24 eyes.

Looking into my question on the internet, in one answer on Quora to the question [Do jellyfish have eyes?](https://www.quora.com/Do-jellyfish-have-eyes), it is said that:

> While box jellyfish have eyes, they cannot process images at all because they simply don't have the central nervous system to process images [Source: GRE Biology question I got right].

I heard somewhere though that box jellyfish do have a nervous system and they can see with their eyes.

I have found answers on Quora to be a bit hit and miss with their accuracy and wondered what the facts are.

Answer (score 2):

This [article](https://www.livescience.com/7243-jellyfish-human-eyes.html?_gl=1*3wuso0*_ga*YW1wLVg5ejlGN0NTZGZVanIwMzlfTVZZcjlUaDdSZGdUV1JmZGo2eDJCLXhWWGZqUnNuYnR6TzZVQzZ1RUx0NkRVbEM.) from Live Science provides some insight (no pun intended) into box jellyfish eyes.

“Whereas we have one set of multi-purpose eyes that sense color, size, shape and light intensity, box jellyfish have four different types of special-purpose eyes. The most primitive set detects only light levels, but one set of eyes is more sophisticated and can detect the color and size of objects.”

[This](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/04/110428123938.htm) article from Science Daily may also help.

“The researchers examined the function of one of two types of "upper lens eyes," already known to form images, to work out just what those eyes can see and how well. It turns out that those four eyes cover precisely the visual field needed to see through the water's surface up into the world above.”